# Unable to navigate from app bar after setting focusable attribute

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview, focus

I am creating a very simple WebView app with a few useful links and I want the initial focus to be on the app bar with easy access to the menu. This works if I add focusable attributes to the layout in main.xml

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

However I'm unable to navigate away from the app bar to the WebView content below unless I add requestFocus to the menu actions:

```
case R.id.url:
webView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
webView.requestFocus();
```

Then I can navigate down to the WebView content below, but as soon as I return to the app bar navigation is lost again. How can I freely navigate away from the app bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added the following code to main.xml and it solves my issue

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/webview"
```